# Make a footer stay down, no matter what

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a footer that stays on the bottom of the page, so when you scroll down it should stay there.

How can I do this the best?

PS: I do not have any code yet, I am just looking for how I can do this the best way possible.

Comment: possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076201/html-css-sticky-footer-growing-content
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/problems-with-css-sticky-footer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822825/sticky-footer-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code on the Footer to make it stay fixed at the bottom.

**For Instance,**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="footer"><!-- Your footer code should be here. --></div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

This will make the footer to stay at the bottom keeping it fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a comment: iOS has problems with that. Just a question: Do you see anything for handling that?

Comment: Making the body to have `position:relative;` would be the best way to overcome this issue. - @dollarvar

Comment: Check out this link as a reference - http://runastartup.com/overlay-scrolling-issues-on-iphone-ipad/ - @dollarvar

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
clear: both;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
height: 3em;
margin-top: -3em;
}

This CSS can help you.
 For better explanation refer to this
 http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/
 This blog can also do the needful
 http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/
```